# Regular expression to identify groups

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

```
content = "[row1|col1]:{value:{{calculate}}<<report_1>>[Row2|col2];format:float;} [hiddenr0120a|c0012]:{format:float;}"
regex = re.compile(r"(\[.*?\]).*?\{(.*?)\}")
entries = regex.findall(content)
#Output
[('[row1|col1]', 'value:{{calculate'), ('[Row2|col2]', 'format:float;')]
#Expected Output
[("[row1|col]", "{value:{{calculate}}<<report_1>>[Row2|col2];format: float;}"), ("[hiddenr0120a|c0012]", "{format:float;}")]
```

I have tried regex "([.*?]).*?{(.*?)}" which actually ends at the first instance of "}", so it fails for the first scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use

```
(\[[^\[\]\r\n]*\]):({.*?})(?: (?=\[)|$)
```

In parts

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\[[^\[\]\r\n]*\]` Match from opening till closing square bracket
- `)` Close group 1
- `:` Match literally (Or use `.*?` to match other chars as well)
- `(` Capture group 2

  - `{.*?}` Match from `{` till `}` as least as possible
- `)` Close **group 2**
- `(?:` Non capture group
   `(?=[)` Match a space and assert what is on the right is `[`

  - `|` Or
  - `$` Assert the end of the string
- `)` close non capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9raaQW/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/suqNZT)

Example code

```
import re
 
content = "[row1|col1]:{value:{{calculate}}<<report_1>>[Row2|col2];format:float;} [hiddenr0120a|c0012]:{format:float;}"
regex = re.compile(r"(\[[^\[\]\r\n]*\]):({.*?})(?: (?=\[)|$)")
entries = regex.findall(content)
print (entries)
```

Output

```
[('[row1|col1]', '{value:{{calculate}}<<report_1>>[Row2|col2];format:float;}'), ('[hiddenr0120a|c0012]', '{format:float;}')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use additional capture groups, and extract like this:

```
import re

text = "[row1|col1]:{value:{{calculate}}<<report_1>>[Row2|col2];format:float;} [hiddenr0120a|c0012]:{format:float;}"
pattern = r'(\[.*?\]).*?\{(.*?\})\s(\[.*\])\:(\{.*\})'
regex = re.compile(pattern)
entries = re.findall(regex, text)

for entry in entries[0]:
    print(entry)
```

Returning:

```
[row1|col1]
value:{{calculate}}<<report_1>>[Row2|col2];format:float;}
[hiddenr0120a|c0012]
{format:float;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the second group always ended with `;}`, then the regular expression may be as simple as
`(\[.+?\]):(\{.*?;\})`

```
import re
content = '''
[row1|col1]:{value:{{calculate}}<<report_1>>[Row2|col2];format:float;}
[hiddenr0120a|c0012]:{format:float;}
'''
r = re.compile(r'(\[.+?\]):(\{.*?;\})')
expected = [("[row1|col1]", "{value:{{calculate}}<<report_1>>[Row2|col2];format:float;}",),
            ("[hiddenr0120a|c0012]", "{format:float;}",),]
assert all(t == expected[i][j] for i, x in enumerate(r.findall(content)) for j, t in enumerate(x))
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/YHW37945).